# Given any compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the closure of the interior of the set is also compact.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

In my Advanced Calculus class we had this excercise and I don't know if this proof is correct.

Using the Heine-Borel Theorem, any set A in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact iff A it's closed and bounded.
So if A is compact, I have to prove $\overline{A^°}$ is closed and bounded.

$\overline{A^°}$ is closed because it's the same as $\overline{\overline{A^°}}$. The reason behind that for any set B, $\overline{B}$ = $\overline{\overline{B}}$

Then, the only thing we have to prove is that A is bounded.
If A is compact $\rightarrow$ A is bounded $\rightarrow$ $A^o$ is bounded. Now we prove that $\overline{A^°}$ is bounded.
So given any $x \in \overline{A^°}$, $\forall r>0, B_r(x)\cap K^° \neq \emptyset$. So if $K^°$ is bounded, there exists $\epsilon$ such as $K^° \subseteq B_\epsilon (x)$. But if  $x \in \overline{A^°}$, there is $\tilde\epsilon > \epsilon > 0$ such as $ B_\epsilon(x)\subseteq B_\tilde\epsilon(x)$.
Because this is for every $x \in \overline{A^°}$, we can bound every element of $ \overline{A^°}$ and the union of all the balls is an open set that bounds $x \in \overline{A^°}$.

Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

It is easier than you are making it. The closure of a set is the intersection of all closed sets containing the set. Since the interior of a compact set is a subset of the compact set and the compact set is closed, the intersection of all closed sets containing the interior, i.e. the closure, is a subset of the compact set. Since the compact set is bounded, so is the closure. Therefore, the closure of the interior is compact.

Comment: Thanks! We didn't see in class that "The closure of a set is the intersection of all closed sets containing the set", but you made me realize another proof:
$A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$
$A^° \subseteq A = \overline{A}$ (since A is closed)
Then $A^° \subseteq \overline{A} \rightarrow \overline{A^°} \subseteq \overline{\overline{A}} = \overline{A} = A$
Since $A$ is bounded, so it is $\overline{A^°}$.
And $\overline{\overline{A^°}}$ is closed.
Then $\overline{A^°}$ is compact.